# Run maven install programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, text-editor

I am writing a program in Java (using no IDE, just plain Text Editor), and I came to a problem.

So basically, I need to programmatically run a maven install on a pom.xml file. Like in Eclipse, you would right click the project, [**Run As** > **Maven Install**]. But what I'd like to do is make *my* program run the maven install on a specified pom file.

Also, I am have a problem finding the download for the Java Maven Library, so that would be useful if you could also post that with your reply!

The program I am writing is going to be distributed with quite a lot of people, and I don't want them to have to install Maven on their computer to be able to use it, so it would be best if I were to use some Maven API or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find your maven files via your M2_HOME environment variable.

In order to call this from Java, you will have to create a Process (Look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)) to open a terminal and execute a "mvn clean install".

Comment: The program I am writing is going to be distributed with quite alot of people, and I don't want them to have to install maven on their computer to be able to use it... :(

Comment: Then you will have to ship with maven packaged next to your application. In which case, the same applies but you need to just traverse the path manually to your maven dir.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You have to use ProcessBuilder to open a terminal and execute the maven goals, and well you need maven to execute the goals, this is how netbeans works, if you download netbeans and check the directories you can see that in the directory `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java`  you have the folder `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven` with maven.